# I am getting a syntax error on a hstore variable at insert

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2, hstore

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;

CREATE TABLE skm_employee_skillset
(
    employee_id                   integer PRIMARY KEY,
    created_date                  DATE DEFAULT current_date,
    last_update                   DATE DEFAULT current_date,
    created_by                    integer NOT NULL,
    updated_by                    integer NOT NULL,
    employee_skill_values         hstore
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION skm_skills_manager__employee_skillset_insert(
                v_employee_id           integer,
                v_user              integer,
                v_skill_type_prefix         char(2),
                v_skill_type_id             integer,
                v_skill_level_confirmed         boolean,
                v_skill_level_confirmed_by      integer )

  RETURNS boolean AS '

BEGIN    

    Insert into skm_employee_skillset
        (employee_id ,
        created_date,
        last_update ,
        created_by,
        updated_by,
        employee_skill_values)
    VALUES
        (v_employee_id,
        DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT,
        v_user,
        v_user,
        '"skill_type_prefix" => v_skill_type_prefix,
         "skill_type_id" => v_skill_type_id,
         "skill_level_confirmed"    => v_skill_level_confirmed, 
         "skill_level_confirmed_by" => v_skill_level_confirmed_by' );

    return TRUE; 
EXCEPTION
    when others then return FALSE;

end;' language 'plpgsql';
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""skill_type_prefix""
>   LINE 508:      '"skill_type_prefix" => v_skill_type_prefix,
>                   ^**

Comment: wrong single quote before ` '"skill_type_prefix" `

Comment: I had been using the tutorials at http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-hstore/ which show the single quotes but.............now when I remove them I getERROR:  column "skill_type_prefix" does not exist
LINE 14:       "skill_type_prefix" => v_skill_type_prefix,

Comment: construct with `hstore(text[], text[])` : hstore(ARRAY['skill_type_prefix','skill_type_id','skill_level_confirmed','skill_level_confirmed_by'], ARRAY[v_skill_type_prefix::TEXT,v_skill_type_id::TEXT,v_skill_level_confirmed::TEXT,v_skill_level_confirmed_by::TEXT])

Answer (score 0):

When the block of code is delimited by single quotes, you cannot use unquoted single quotes inside the block of code itself, because **single quotes do not nest**.

The easiest solution is to use a specific [dollar-quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) delimiter for the code body, such as in

```
CREATE FUNCTION name(arguments...) RETURNS ...
AS $BODY$

   ...
   ... body of the function
   ...

 $BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Once this part is solved, you can focus on the syntax of your hstore as a string literal value, freely using single quotes to enclose this value.

Comment: Thanks guys, Daniels answer has almost got me done. The only thing is that the hStore values show as below with the v_ variable names but I need their values "skill_level"=>"v_skill_level", "skill_type_id"=>"v_skill_type_id", "skill_type_prefix"=>"v_skill_type_prefix", "skill_level_confirmed"=>"v_skill_level_confirmed", "skill_level_confirmed_by"=>"v_skill_level_confirmed_by""

Comment: Any hint on how to get the values from the v_ fields into Hstore instead of the names?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;


CREATE TABLE skm_employee_skillset
(
    employee_id                   integer PRIMARY KEY,
    created_date                  DATE DEFAULT current_date,
    last_update                   DATE DEFAULT current_date,
    created_by                    integer NOT NULL,
    updated_by                    integer NOT NULL,
    employee_skill_values         hstore
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION skm_skills_manager__employee_skillset_insert(
                v_employee_id           integer,
                v_user              integer,
                v_skill_type_prefix         char(2),
                v_skill_type_id             integer,
                v_skill_level_confirmed         boolean,
                v_skill_level_confirmed_by      integer )
RETURNS boolean AS $$
BEGIN    

    Insert into skm_employee_skillset
        (employee_id ,
        created_date,
        last_update ,
        created_by,
        updated_by,
        employee_skill_values)
    VALUES
        (v_employee_id,
        DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT,
        v_user,
        v_user,
        hstore(ARRAY['skill_type_prefix','skill_type_id','skill_level_confirmed','skill_level_confirmed_by']
             , ARRAY[v_skill_type_prefix::TEXT,v_skill_type_id::TEXT,v_skill_level_confirmed::TEXT,v_skill_level_confirmed_by::TEXT]) );

    return TRUE; 
EXCEPTION
    when others then return FALSE;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;


select skm_skills_manager__employee_skillset_insert(4,2,'aa',4,true,2);

select * from skm_employee_skillset;



employee_id |created_date |last_update |created_by |updated_by |employee_skill_values                                                                                             |
------------|-------------|------------|-----------|-----------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
4           |2018-10-09   |2018-10-09  |2          |2          |"skill_type_id"=>"4", "skill_type_prefix"=>"aa", "skill_level_confirmed"=>"true", "skill_level_confirmed_by"=>"2" |
```

Comment: following on, how do I load the values if employee_skill_values is  hstore []? Sorry to be a pest but I am getting there.

Comment: I have found a way but for some reason can't copy it from pgadmin and past it here???? basically I create a hstore type variable and load it using the hstore(Array....as above, then in the values ARRAY[v_hstore]....Thanks for your help.

Comment: by the way, before getting too deep with hstore i suggest you to check jsonb, you've got typed value hstore is text->text only

Comment: Thanks again cske, I will need to upgrade my Postgresql first. In the meantime what would the equivalent syntax be for a JSON type?

Comment: This is what I have (can it be done with ARRAY as above)                                                                                        
       json = '{"skill_id":"'                 || v_skill_id    || '",' ||
                  '"skill_details": {' ||
                  '"skill_level":"'              || v_skill_level || '",' ||
                  '"skill_level_confirmed":"'    || v_skill_level || '",' ||                  
                  '"skill_level_confirmed_by":"' || v_skill_level_confirmed_by || '"}}';

Comment: @Gary be carefull json and jsonb are different, you can use [jsonb_build_object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: Thanks again, looks like I need to upgrade Postgresql so I can take advantage of the jasonb types. I am fairly new at this type of stuff (come from a mainframe background) so will have to learn how to upgrade on my VMware Workstation as that is where I have the other elements of our project installed.

Comment: Thanks for your effort so far. This works fine in json, how do I rewrite it to use json_build_object?          
   v_json = '{"skill_id":"'                 || v_skill_id    || '",' ||
                  '"skill_details": {' ||
                  '"skill_level":"'              || v_skill_level || '",' ||
                  '"skill_level_confirmed":"'    || v_skill_level || '",' ||                  
                  '"skill_level_confirmed_by":"' || v_skill_level_confirmed_by || '"}}';

Comment: I am confused as to whether this is a valid JSON field content....output of a Raise Notice..... 

({"skill_id":"aa000001","skill_details":"skill_level":"5","skill_level_confirmed":"5","skill_level_confirmed_by":"624"}})

How would I extract the value for skill_level as 5?

Apologies for the simplistic question, I appear to be getting nowhere.

Cheers,
Gary. P.S. how to I keep this formatted?

Comment: you doubled `}` at the end

Comment: My apologies, I must have deleted a '{' before "skill_levels" trying to keep the post formatted.   v_json json; raise notice '>>>> (%)', v_json;
NOTICE:  >>>> ({"skill_id":"aa000001","skill_details":{"skill_level":"5","skill_level_confirmed":"5","skill_level_confirmed_by":"624"}})

Comment: Thanks for your help. The missing '{' was just part of making the post here. My problem is still the same.